# Error executing tsc on ngconf2015demo - missing tsd.d.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsd

Trying to setup Angular2 with Visual Studio 2015RC on Windows, and following [TodoMVC application demo for ng-conf 2015](https://github.com/Microsoft/ngconf2015demo/blob/master/readme.md) instructions, I get to the point where `tsd reinstall` produces the following output:

```
c:\...>tsd reinstall
>> tsd 0.5.7
-> running reinstall
>> written 1 file:
    - angular2/angular2.d.ts
```

and it creates `typings` folder, but the only thing in it is the above `angular2/angular2.d.ts`

The contents of `tsd.json` is:

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "angular2/angular2.d.ts": {
      "commit": "b3834d886a95789e6ab56e8244775ec10c5293d0"
    }
  }
}
```

So when I try to execute the next command, per the demo setup steps `tsc`, I get this error:

```
C:\...> tsc
error TS6053: File 'typings/tsd.d.ts' not found.
```

What am I doing wrong, that causes that file to not be where expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a.) Update tsd please `npm update tsd -g`.

b.) To reinstall and save to tsd.d.ts you need to use the `save` option : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#reinstall-definitions

`tsd reinstall -so`